# How can this function use a variable while defining it in calloc?

Tags: c

This is an example usage from the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) of `pthread_create`.

I am interested in this line:

```c
struct thread_info *tinfo = calloc(num_threads, sizeof(*tinfo));
```

In seems `tinfo` is declared here, but it's also used in the argument to `calloc`. Is this equivalent to the below snippet?

```c
struct thread_info *tinfo;
tinfo = calloc(num_threads, sizeof(*tinfo));
```

I'm unsure how `tinfo` can be used before it's declared in the first snippet.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? Quotes from the C standard? I mean it's pretty obvious that the answer is "because the C standard allows it" but I guess you are looking for more than that...

Comment: A high level explanation of what's happening here. I am guessing that the second snippet is equivalent, but not sure. In a C statement `int *var = something(*var)` is the variable `var` created first? Coming from duck typing languages, this is confusing.

Comment: Here is another variable definition that you may find "interresting": `int n = some_function(&n);`

Comment: Anyway.... read the line from left to right then there is no mystery

Comment: "Is this equivalent to the below snippet?" yes. It's different mechanisms being used but the end result is the same.

Comment: I actually find `int n = some_function(&n)` interesting! I have never seen that usage before.

Comment: Yes, both of your code snippets are strictly equivalent.

Comment: Hint: sizeof is not a function. It is an operator. You could use `tinfo = calloc(num_threads, sizeof *tinfo );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the man entry for `pthread_create`, the `struct thread_info` is declared previously:

```
struct thread_info {    /* Used as argument to thread_start() */
           pthread_t thread_id;        /* ID returned by pthread_create() */
           int       thread_num;       /* Application-defined thread # */
           char     *argv_string;      /* From command-line argument */
       };
```

So, when calling calloc, the compiler knows the size of the struct. The code is equivalent to specify the following:

```
struct thread_info *tinfo = calloc(num_threads, sizeof(struct thread_info));
```

Comment: The compiler knows the size of the struct but the calloc argument is `sizeof(*tinfo)`. Could you please explain a bit more on how the compiler knows `*tinfo` is `struct thread_info`? Clearly it hasn't been declared before this line.

Comment: When de-referencing the inner `*tinfo` (inside the sizeof), the compiler is aware of the type (`struct thread_info`) of such pointer. In other words, `tinfo` points to a struct thread_info, of which the compiler already knows the size.

Comment: I thought the same at first - but @sprajagopal question is valid - cos the variable is undeclared at that point, so the compiler does not know the type.

Comment: It's a matter of compilation vs. execution, I think. At compilation time, the compiler's syntactic analyzer checks that the type of the variable within the `sizeof` is known, and generates the code accordingly. In that sense, it's not a matter of the variable being declared or not, but its type and size. At execution time, the right hand side of the assignment is therefore executed successfully, since the compiler has 'transformed' this call into something like 'reserve a memory chunk of this fixed size'.

Comment: @wired What makes you think the variable "is undeclared"? Try: `int n = some_function(&n);`

Comment: By the time the compiler reads the `=`, the `tinfo` variable is fully defined. Its name and type (and thus its size) are fully known to the compiler. As also `struct thread_info` is fully known, there is nothing 'unknown' in the call to `calloc`.